# Why are NULL values returned first if the sorting is DESC in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

When the NULL ordering is not specified, then the handling of the NULL values is:

- NULL values are last if the sorting is ASC
- NULL values are first if the sorting is DESC

Why is this so?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

It is written in the Oracle Documentation:

> If the null ordering is not specified then the handling of the null values is:
> NULLS LAST if the sort is ASC
> NULLS FIRST if the sort is DESC

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html) it is.

Comment: Also note from the documentation linked, that placement of the nulls can be changed, if desired, `DESC NULLS LAST`.